# How to turn square brackets into curly brackets?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I'm using the forest environment to draw systems/trees. This is the tree I am drawing. In the tree there are five brackets. However, I would like to turn the first square bracket (the one embracing AGÊNCIA and TIPO DE PROCESSO) into a curly bracket. Is it possible? How?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
        for tree={
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
            grow=0,
            reversed, 
            parent anchor=east,
            child anchor=west, 
            anchor=west,
            %if n children=0{tier=word}{} 
        }
        [\textsc{oração}
        [\textsc{agência}]
        [\textsc{tipo de processo}
        [material
        [transformativo
        [resultativo]
        [não-resultativo]
        ]
        [criativo]
        ]
        [mental]
        [relacional
        [atributivo]
        [identificador]
        ]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture for the code above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

May not be perfect, but to my tase quite close ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,
        reversed,
        parent anchor=east,
        child anchor=west,
        anchor=west,
if level=1{edge={rounded corners}}{},
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
        calign=edge midpoint,
        }
[\textsc{oração}
    [\textsc{agência},]
    [\textsc{tipo de processo}
        [material
            [transformativo
                [resultativo]
                [não-resultativo]
            ]
        [criativo]
        ]
        [mental]
        [relacional
            [atributivo]
            [identificador]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Or you more prefer zo have calligraphic brace?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        grow=0,
        reversed,
        parent anchor=east,
        child anchor=west,
        anchor=west, 
if level=1{no edge}{},
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}](!u.parent anchor) -- +(5pt,0) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};},
        s sep=4mm,
        calign=edge midpoint,
%
/tikz/BC/.style = {decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=2mm,
        raise=#1},% for mirroring of brace
        very thick,
        pen colour=black},
        }
[\textsc{oração}
    [\textsc{agência}, name=A]
    [\textsc{tipo de processo}, name=B
        [material
            [transformativo
                [resultativo]
                [não-resultativo]
            ]
        [criativo]
        ]
        [mental]
        [relacional
            [atributivo]
            [identificador]
        ]
    ]
]
\draw[BC=1mm] (B.west) -- (A.west);
% \draw[BC=1mm] (B.south west) -- (A.north west);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Zarko, this is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks a bunch! What if I want to place the curly bracket in level 2 (in this case, without the midle brench for "mental")? And if I want to place it in level 3, but just to embrace "atributivo" and "identificador"?

Comment: I'll do this. Sorry, I'm new here. Have you seen my answer after editing?

Comment: @JJSilva, I sow your edited question, For some reason you change some nodes content, but this has not influence in proposed solution )you only need to insert correct text into nodes. This should not be a problem.